Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'DAL.vehicleInfo[]
I am creating a REST API client that returns something like this:
{
   "uniqueID": 123456789,
   "plate": "0123456789ABCD",
   "GPSDate": "2021-04-13T07:38:24Z",
   "latitude": 43.12345,
   "longitude": -3.12345,
   "speed": 120,
   "course": 325,
   "odometer": 205486.732,
   "receivedDate": "2021-04-13T07:38:24Z",
   "stateInfo": {
      "stateData": {
         "stateParam": "50+",
         "stateDetail": "12345"
      }
   },
   "GPSQuality": 1,
   "CANInfo": {
      "CANData": {
         "CANParam": "RPM",
         "CANValue": "3250"
      }
   },
   "peripheralsInfo": {
      "peripheralsData": {
         "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
         "peripheralsValue": "En marcha"
      }
   },
   "geofenceInfo": {
      "geofenceData": {
         "geofencePoint": "Punto 1",
         "geofencePolygon": "Geocerca Poligonal 1"
      }
   }
}

To do this, I created the following classes:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CANData
    {
        public string? CANParam { get; set; }
        public string? CANValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL
{
    public class geofenceData
    {
        public string? geofencePoint { get; set; }
        public string? geofencePolygon { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL
{
    public class peripheralsData
    {
        public string? peripheralsParam { get; set; }
        public string? peripheralsValue { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL
{
    public class stateData
    {
        public string? stateParam { get; set; }
        public string? stateDetail { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL
{
    public class vehicleInfo
    {
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public int course { get; set; }
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public stateData[]? stateInfo { get; set; }
        public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
        public CANData[]? CANInfo { get; set; }
        public peripheralsData[]? peripheralsInfo { get; set; }
        public geofenceData? geofenceInfo { get; set; }
    }
}

These are the methods we are using:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using DAL;

namespace BIL
{
    public class FlotasNetClient
    {
        private static string? _baseUrl;
        private static string? _username;
        private static string? _sha256Concatenado;
        private static string? _company;

        public FlotasNetClient()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            _baseUrl = builder.GetSection("baseUrl").Value;
            _username = builder.GetSection("username").Value;
            _sha256Concatenado = builder.GetSection("sha256Concatenado").Value;
            _company = builder.GetSection("company").Value;
        }

        public async Task<vehicleInfo[]> GetVehicleInfoByDate()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-09T01%3A00%3A00Z&enddate=2024-10-09T01%3A05%3A00Z"),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "user-agent", "vscode-restclient" },
                    { "accept", "application/json" },
                    { "user", _username },
                    { "password", _sha256Concatenado },
                    { "company", _company },
                },
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                var Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vehicleInfo[]>(body);
                return Deserialized;
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the program.cs file:
using BIL;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var client = new FlotasNetClient();
var vehicleData = await client.GetVehicleInfoByDate();

At compile time this error occurs:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'DAL.vehicleInfo[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'message', line 1, position 11.'

Seeing the error, I changed the data type from vehicleInfo[] to List<vehicleInfo>, but the error continued to appear at compile time.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.vehicleInfo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'message', line 1, position 11.'


The error states that you're trying to deserialize an object in to a collection of objects. You might also try including the JSON and the code you're using to try and deserialize it.

Your question might be a duplicate of Getting error deserialising JSON to List or How to load data from distinct .json file to List, C#? or even Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException problem while trying to deserialize with a model, but we cannot answer without a [mcve] that includes 1) Sample JSON, and 2) Your call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json) -- specifically we need to know the type T you are deserializing to.  See [ask].

Your JSON sample is malformed, if I upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ I get multiple errors.  And when I try to compile your code, I get The type or namespace name could not be found for 'stateDataList', 'peripheralsDataList' and 'geofenceData', see https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwbNPv.

Now if I comment out the properties for the missing types and make a guess on how to fix the JSON by adding an extra } before the final ], then the fixed JSON can be deserialized successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2tvpL.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], as it is your code looks OK and seems to work correctly.  Absent a way to reproduce your problem, your question may get closed as needing debugging details.  Thanks!

We corrected it by removing the [] from all the parameters (state Data[], CANData[], peripheralsData[]) the only one we left the same was public async Task<vehicleInfo[]> GetVehicleInfoByDate() and var Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vehicleInfo []>(body);

@GermanDavid - This question came up in the reopen queue, do you still need help with this, or does your comment indicate the question is resolved to your satisfaction?
